# Does nginx support FastCGI local redirect responses?

Tags: nginx, apache2, fastcgi

RFC 3875 specifies a [Local Redirect Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-6.2.2), which, in short says:

*If* the script sends a "Location:" header with a local path (i.e. starting with /, not with a protocol) and a Status Code 200 header, *then* the web server should interpret and fulfil this request as if the client had requested the **file** specified by the "Location:" header.

This works in Apache with the (now deprecated/hard to find mod_fastcgi) and in [lighttpd](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2108), but [not in Apache mod_fcgid](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61430).

I couldn't find any information about that for nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx doesn't support this. But you could use `X-Accel-Redirect` header for internal redirect

`X-Accel-Redirect: /location`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_ignore_headers

> “X-Accel-Redirect” performs an internal redirect to the specified URI;

Comment: Thanks. It's annoying that there is a standard but it's not fully implemented and instead we have to rely on proprietary headers.